# How do Python modules work

Tags: python, module, load, location, customization

I was wondering how do Python modules work?
Say I want to make my Python program some custom modules to package with it, where would I put them in relation to the main .py file?(and how would I load them if not using the usual way)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If the module is specific to your program, you can put into the same directory as the main script. From the [documentation](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/modules.html#the-module-search-path):

> When a module named `spam` is imported, the interpreter searches for a file named spam.py in the directory containing the input script and then in the list of directories specified by the environment variable PYTHONPATH.

I would recommend that you read the entire [tutorial on modules](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/modules.html). It's pretty short and has a lot of useful info.